# jQuery remove() for each if class contains text

Tags: jquery, if-statement, each, contains

Trying to remove what is in the class 'bnum' IF the title (class name='productnamecolor colors_productname') contains the text 'True'.

Basically in the below example you SHOULD NOT be able to see any "Burkett Bucks" value under the 'True Merchandiser Refrigerator', however it should still be on all the others:

```
<table width="300px">
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" valign="top"><a class="productnamecolor colors_productname" href=""> Star Griddle</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" valign="top"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="64%" valign="top"><font class="text colors_text rewardpoints"><span id="offers">Special Offers:</span><br>
                <div class="bbucks"><img src="http://bit.ly/ihYMFL" id="bucks"> Earn <span class="bnum">2343</span> Burkett Bucks</div>
                </font></td>
              <td align="right" width="36%"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" valign="top"><a class="productnamecolor colors_productname" href=""> True Merchandiser Refrigerator</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" valign="top"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="64%" valign="top"><font class="text colors_text rewardpoints"><span id="offers">Special Offers:</span><br>
                <div class="bbucks"><img src="http://bit.ly/ihYMFL" id="bucks"> Earn <span class="bnum">2343</span> Burkett Bucks</div>
                </font></td>
              <td align="right" width="36%"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" valign="top"><a class="productnamecolor colors_productname" href="">Generic Something</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" valign="top"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="64%" valign="top"><font class="text colors_text rewardpoints"><span id="offers">Special Offers:</span><br>
                <div class="bbucks"><img src="http://bit.ly/ihYMFL" id="bucks"> Earn <span class="bnum">2343</span> Burkett Bucks</div>
                </font></td>
              <td align="right" width="36%"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Problem I'm having is that it is doing it for all values, I only want to remove the value under EACH title that has the word 'True' in it.  So im assuming something wrong with my EACH.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(".colors_productname:contains('True')").each(function () {
        $('.bnum').remove(); });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of a global selector

```
$('.bnum')
```

you need to use the current context of the each method in your function, taking into account that the base is not in the same tr as the target we will need do a little Dom traversal.

```
$(".colors_productname:contains('True')").each(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('.bnum').remove(); });
```

Comment: This did not work either, I think these are all really valid unfortunately the 'Title' and the class 'bnum' are in separate 'TR's..perhaps this is where we are running into the problem

Comment: Ah, missed that, the html was getting pretty jumbled on my display. Updated to do the correct Dom traversal before removing.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be `$(this).find('.bnum').remove()` or even shorter:
`$(".colors_productname:contains('True') .bnum").remove()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".colors_productname:contains('True')").each(function () {
        $(this).find('.bnum').remove(); });
});
```

Comment: There's no need for `.each()` at all.